# Use a separate form in Jquery step

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-steps

I want to use a form inside the jquery-step,But when I do thisو The step is completely lost;

```html
<form action="#" id="form1" method="post" class="validation-wizard wizard-circle" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <form id="trp-form">
     <input type="hidden" value="trp" name="mode">
```

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

I want to insert an uploader that has a form inside it into a jquery-step

Comment: You cannot nest `form` elements. It's not clear what you're trying to do, so I can't offer any further help than that

Comment: I want to have a form in the wizard that is related to the upload file and then click next button to go to the next step and see the uploaded files. How can I have a form inside the wizard?